# How can I replace the last character of a string for the first letter of the alphabet?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a code that moves every letter from a word, one letter up, for example: Abc becomes Bcd, (The first letter is always capital), but whenever I type z in a word then it becomes { or [ (if it is a capital letter). For example, if I type zoo, the output is "[pp" I want z to become a. So far I have tried this:

```
 word = input("Insert Word:")
 word = word.capitalize().replace(" ", "")

for shift in word:
  incrypt = chr(ord(shift)+1)
  print (incrypt, end='')
```

I have also tried using if statements like this:

```
word = input("Insert Word:")
word = word.capitalize().replace(" ", "")
    for shift in word:
  incrypt = chr(ord(shift)+1)
  Last_char= incrypt[-1]
  if Last_char > chr(123):
    Last_char = [chr(97)]
    print (incrypt, end='')
  elif Last_char == chr(91):
    Last_char = [chr(65)]
    print (incrypt, end='')
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: In your second code example, is `incrypt = chr(ord(shift)+1) ...` intended to be unindented from the prior `for` loop? Or I guess, is the `for` loop intended to be indented?

Comment: `incrypt = chr(ord(shift)+1) if shift != "z" else "a"`?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"It didn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Your posted code fails to run.  Your code should caontain an explicit check for the letters `z` and `Z`; perhaps you coded them as integers for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this :

```
word = input("Insert Word:")
word = word.capitalize().replace(" ", "")

A,Z = ord('A'), ord('Z')
a,z = ord('a'), ord('z')

step = 1

for shift in word:
    new_char = ord(shift) + step
    
    incrypt = None
    if 'a' <= shift <= 'z':
        incrypt = chr(new_char) if new_char <= z else chr(a + (new_char - z - 1)%26 )
    elif 'A' <= shift <= 'Z':
        incrypt = chr(new_char) if new_char <= Z else chr(A + (new_char - Z - 1)%26 )
    else : 
        incrypt = shift
    print (incrypt, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using join:

```
word = word.lower()

"".join(chr(ord('a') + (ord(w)-ord('a')+1)%26) for w in word).capitalize()
```